# vector resize() automatic fill

Tags: c++, vector, resize

I'm writing a class that holds a matrix (of double values), represented as `vector<vector<double>>`;

I want to implement the `operator=`, to re-fill my matrix with the details of a given sparse matrix. I'm writing the following code:

```
RegMatrix& RegMatrix::operator=(const SparseMatrix rhs){
    if(*this != rhs){
        _matrix.clear();
        _matrix.resize(rhs.getRow());
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<rhs.getRow();++i){
            _matrix.at(i).resize(rhs.getCol());
        }

        for(i=0;i<rhs.getSize();++i){
            Element e = rhs.getElement(i);
            _matrix[e._row][e._col] = e._val; 
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Does the `resize()` method fill automatically the vector with zeros?
Is my implementation ok?

Answer (score 5):

New elements take the `vector` member's default value, or a specific value if you use the overload of `resize` with two parameters.

```
void resize(
   size_type _Newsize,
   Type _Val
);
```

In your case, the default will be an empty `vector<double>` - if that is not what you want, pass what you DO want to put there to the overload above.

Existing elements are not modified.

Comment: so, if i want a two-dimensional vector of the zise RowXCol, and each inner vector's element will have the value of 0, i should change the line so it would look like that:  _matrix.at(i).resize(rhs.getCol(),0);       ?

Comment: @limlim: You don't need to change it. You are already passing that zero *implicitly*. You can also pass that zero explicitly, but it will not change anything. If you believe that passing that 0 explicitly makes your code clearer, then you can go ahead and put it there. But it will make no difference functionality-wise.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, resize won't zero the existing elements. If that's what you want to do, use assign (check out my answer for more).

Comment: @JoshD: The OP's vectors do not have any "existing elements". They are always *empty* before `resize` call.

Comment: @AndreyT, then why does he bother to call clear()? That's a wasteful step. Because this is an assignment operator, it is reasonable to assume that there may be some contents in the _matrix. A call to assign covers both cases and is preferred to calling clear then resize.

Comment: @AndreyT: What part of "re-fill" do you not understand? (And no need to be so loud.)

Comment: @JoshD: Er... He doesn't have any exiting elements *because* he called `clear` in advance. That's what I'm talking about. Why you call it a "wasteful step" is not entirely clear to me. The solution you suggested yourself (with `assign`) is just a wrapper over `clear` (at least by specification) followed by a sequence of even less efficient steps.

Comment: @c-urchin: Huh? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to zero out the entire 2d array, you can use the [assign function of vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/assign/):

```
v.assign(size, vector<double>(size, 0.));
```

This will make a 2d vector of sizeXsize filled with zeros.

In your case:

```
RegMatrix& RegMatrix::operator=(const SparseMatrix rhs){
    if(*this != rhs){
        _matrix.assign(rhs.getRow(), vector<double>(rhs.getCol(), 0.));

        for(i=0;i<rhs.getSize();++i){
            Element e = rhs.getElement(i);
            _matrix[e._row][e._col] = e._val; 
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: No formal need for an explicit `0` as well. `v.assign(size, vector<double>(size))` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

None of `std::vector<>` methods ever use any form of default initialization internally. `std::vector<>` only requires its elements to be *CopyConstructible* and *Assignable*, but does not require them to be *DefaultConstructible*. Every time you run into a situation when some elements seem to be constructed "out of nothing" (as is the case with your `resize` calls) it normally means that the `std::vector<>` method you are using has an extra parameter, which allows you to pass the value from which the new elements will be copy-constructed. We don't often notice that, since these arguments are always supplied with default values equal to the `()`-initailized element of the corresponding type.

In your case, the

```
_matrix.at(i).resize(rhs.getCol());
```

is actually translated into

```
_matrix.at(i).resize(rhs.getCol(), double());
```

call, meaning that formally it is you who's *implicitly* passing the initial value for the new elements.

`double()` evaluates to zero, so yes, the column vectors will be filled with zeros initially.

Comment: No, only the newly-added elements (if any) will be zero.

Comment: @c-urchin: Huh? Firstly, when I say "new elements" a mean newly-added elements, which is sufficiently clear. Secondly, my last remark applies to the specific OP's code, where the vector is *empty* initially. So, it will be *filled* with zeros after resize, as I said.

Comment: Why so touchy? In point of fact, the OP says (please reread it) "re-fill" which implies that some values have already been set.

Comment: @c-urchin: Please, pay attention. The OP's explicitly calls `clear` before doing any other actions. So, there are *no existing elements* at the moment of `resize`. What part of that don't you understand?